# sql delete related records?

Tags: sql, recovery

What is best practice on record deletion?
And which option is most correct?

For example

there is following situation:

tables

> ----users----
>
> int usr_id
>
> varchar name
>
> varchar surname
>
> bool deleted_yn
>
> ---
>
> ---subjects--
>
> int subject_id
>
> varchar title
>
> bool deleted_yn
>
> ---
>
> ---subject_to_user---
>
> int subject_to_user_id
>
> int usr_id
>
> int subject_id
>
> bool deleted_yn
>
> ---

And if I want to delete user or subject do I need delete relation - subject_to_user?

Why I'm asking, because at work sometimes user deletes some information and then we must recover that data.
At the moment we delete related data, but recovery is very difficult;

So I'm asking what is best practice on deletion?
And which option is most correct?

I think that deletion related data is correct, but it depends on situation.

By deleting there I mean marking deleted_yn true/false

Answer (score 3):

Best practice is not to delete anything. Just flag an item as deleted

Add column 'IsDeleted' and in most of the queries you add the 'WHERE IsDeleted=False'

Comment: of course by deleting there i mean, marking - deleted_yn; So question is the same, do I need mark related dataa as deleted?

Comment: Especially if you currently do a lot of data recovery.

Comment: Its depends on the structure of the DB - If you want all the related data to be marked as deleted or not...

Comment: I like this too. That way your primary keys remain "unique" even if deleted. No numbers reused.

Comment: This is an old topic and somethings have changed since the question. The best practice described here is contradicting with the EU data regulations in some cases. In some cases the data actually really needs to be removed from the database.

To remove related data, one needs to combine the related data to the delete clause. There is some variation in different databases, but for example postgresql allows delete "USING" another table. Read more in https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-delete-join/

Answer (score 0):

The related data in subject_to_user is related how? With ID's.

If you delete from user and subject but not subject_to_user, what tells you that you won't create a new user with an ID that is already in subject_to_user?

The idea is to remove all related data. If you need recovery, you can always have another set of tables called deleted_user, deleted_subject, and deleted_subject_to_user. When you delete from your main tables, move to those just before.

Comment: idea: move data to table by prefix delete_ make some sense, I'l keep that in mind and try this :)

Comment: You just need twice the tables.

Comment: If you take this approach, you might also add a deleted_dt field to make it easier to restore by date/time.

Answer (score 0):

Udi Dahan (am man whom I am unashamedly influenced by) wrote an excellent blog post on this topic. You can read about it [here](http://www.udidahan.com/2009/09/01/dont-delete-just-dont/) but the summary is to mirror what happens in real life.

For example in the real world an order is "cancelled", "returned" but never really deleted - with context being extremely important.

Answer (score 0):

Marking data as removed in the database is great, but in some cases you might need to really delete data from your database to conform with data regulations.

When using postgresql you can delete related data with the "USING" keyword to combine the delete query to the related table. For example

```
DELETE FROM observed_topics 
  USING analyzed_documents
  WHERE analyzed_documents.id = observed_topics.document_id
  AND analyzed_documents.author = 'the_man_with_the_right_to_be_forgotten';
DELETE FROM analyzed_documents
  WHERE author = 'the_man_with_the_right_to_be_forgotten';
```

will first delete `observed_topics` related to some documents and in the second statement we delete the actual documents.